# How does GIT client deals with wrong SSL settings of repository?

Tags: java, git, ssl, https

For my personal pet-project I wrote on Java application, which pulls code from GIT repository through https and performs some analysis. However when I started testing it against code store in corporate repository I got “PKIX path building failed” and “unable to find valid certification path to requested target” errors.

Quick googling showed that the main cause of the problem is incorrect SSL settings in the infrastructure like self-signed certificate, for example.

I found possible workarounds to avoid this error:

1. Add host certificate manually into JRE trusted certificates.
2. Dynamically add the certificate to trusted certificates from applications resource files during its startup.
3. During startup of the app disable SSL validations at all, but this makes application vulnerable to "man in the middle" attacks.
   But that's not the question.

When I was working with this corporate repository with standard GIT client (through https too) I've never got any issues with SSL or certificates. So the question is - how does official GIT client avoids this problem with self signed certificate in the chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git itself does not do anything with any of this.

Git uses helpers—external programs and libraries—when talking to other Git providers.  Those programs and libraries are responsible for all of this.  So if you use `git fetch` or `git push`—note that `git pull` uses `git fetch`—and you use these with a URL that begins with `https://`, Git uses a system-provided HTTPS library,<sup>1</sup> usually called "libcurl" or just `curl`.  If you use an `ssh://` URL, Git uses the system-provided `ssh`.

The [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/) includes a chapter on Git Internals, with one section dedicated to [Environment Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/).  When using libcurl, these variables are particularly useful:

- `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` prints out the same stuff that `curl -v` prints.
- `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` turns off SSL certificate verification.  So the default must be to *do* that verification, which (of course) will have issues with self-signed certificates.

> When I was working with this corporate repository with standard GIT client (through https too) I've never got any issues with SSL or certificates.

That's interesting and curious; perhaps invoking Git with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` set will show what's going on here, or perhaps not.  Or, perhaps the libcurl that was used to build your particular Git uses some CA files that your Java libraries do not.

---

<sup>1</sup>The details for this will depend on how your Git binaries were built.  If you like, you can get the source code for Git and build it yourself, and thus have control over which library is used.